# Moving screen to focused area html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, mobile-safari

I've got a html5 form and a submit button(original, I know).
When the user fills out the form incorrectly and presses the html  **< button ... />**  tag, the focus goes to the first error message. This is expected and good behaviour and all is well.
However, when the user presses **GO** on both chrome and safari the focus does not move.

I tried debugging by printing out the document.activeElement after I set the focus.
It prints the same html element when I press go and when I press the form button, even though the focus is not on this particular element when i press GO.

In short:

- Press **HTML** button - use jquery to apply focus to desired error input. Works like a charm.
- Press **GO** button - use same function to apply focus to the desired error input.
  The user does not get anything.

Code examples:

Markup:

```
<form class="boxBody form" action="#" id="profileForm">  
    <input type="text" class="keyboardInput" id="customer-email" name="email" tabindex="1" size="28" maxlength="128">  
   //More inputs  
    <button id="profileSubmit" data-localize="{'text': 'profileBox.submit'}" tabindex="11" class="save-profile btn btn-red"></button>  
</form>
```

.js:

```
$('#profileForm').submit(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    updateProfile(event);  
//updateProfile validates the form and creates error messages
    setFocusOnUpdate();
    console.log(document.activeElement);
 //prints the same dom element.
});
```

And

```
function setFocusOnUpdate(){
var successMessage = $(".alert-success:visible", widgetElement);  

if( successMessage.length > 0 )
{
    //Success message gets focus
    widgetElement.find("input, select").last().focus();
}
else
{               
    //First error message gets focus
    var firstVisibleAlert = $(".alert:visible", widgetElement)[0];
    $(firstVisibleAlert).parent().find("input, select").focus();
}           
}
```

Thing is, in both instances, **GO** and **< button / >**, the desired element gets focus, but the screen only moves to the element when I use the button. How can I get the screen to move when pressing go also?

Can some wizard please help me? Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using anchors on the same page to get your desired effect?

Isn't it possible to set anchors by the forms so that when you want the focus to be set too a  certain input it does so by moving your screen to the anchor?

Comment: Why do i need an anchor when I have an input element with an id?  
the focus is on the right object, the screen just does not move.

Comment: And an anchor should make the screen move. I was just weighing in on an idea I had.

Comment: Yes, I have experimented with moving the screen to the input displaying an error like so,  

    $("window").scrollTop($(':focus').offset().top);  
This moves the viewport to the location. But I want focus to behave g**damnit. I don't want to move the sceen manually. Definetly not a bad idea though, just not a true fix or reason for this strange stuff.